# Could a quantum computer be integrated into a biological medium?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, artificial-intelligence, ecology, quantum

I'm working on an idea for an AI in a short story and have been circling around the idea of a biologically-integrated quantum computer — think, diamond qubits suspended in a biological medium (goop?) that contains a self-sustaining ecosystem where the elements of the ecosystem (fungi, plant roots, small bugs, etc) have been genetically engineered to connect the qubits and communicate algorithms.

Setting aside the coldness issue, what am I missing that I would need to explain or explore?

Comment: The question as written is just a jumble of buzzwords. There are already biological computers. They are called brains and nervous systems. Working quantum computers are not real. What makes your "quantum computer" different from a normal brain? Once you have that figured out -- once you decide what you are asking for actually is and does -- then you can ask is it plausible.

Comment: A lot of the diamond qbit stuff is interrogated with light. But other than that diamond is probably pretty good from a biocompatibility perspective. There is probably some hand waving about how to connect biologically to the diamond unless they are engineered to have some kind of interface to a cell membrane or something…

Comment: Is there quantum computing going on in brains? We don't know, there could be. Nothing really saying their could not be.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor No, we're very sure that our brains do not use quantum computing. Quantum computing requires a very precise minimum level of phase coherence, and nothing in biology at room temperature has ever demonstrated that capability. Certainly nothing in brains - we know what neurons are made of, it's not like we could've missed this. As for the main question, my advice would be that it would be better not to explain it rather than to try to make a convincing string of technobabble (similar to L Dutch's answer, though I'd raise my eyebrows at "neurons work due to some quantum phenomena").

Comment: @VentifactsandYardangs Biochemistry operates at quantum scales, that is quantum mechanics is required to explain certain things such as chemistry in general. To say those features can't and have never been taken advantage of is false,.  Brains probably don't do quantum computing, however nothing in theory forbids them from being able to do quantum computing.

Comment: @VentifactsandYardangs: The words *very sure* and *brain* do not mix. Biology doesn't have nano-tech, biology *is* nano-tech. Never second-guess the results of relentless natural selection and optimization.

Comment: @Daron "Working quantum computer are not real" - you mean gate-based QC with hundreds of qubits aren't real, right? Because gate-based QC definitely have been built multiple times.  On the other hand quantum annealing computers are even a lot more real and usable already (cf. the company D-wave).

Comment: I'm not saying that it's impossible for evolution to produce a biological quantum computer - evolution is very difficult to overestimate, and I wouldn't bet against it. What I *am* sure of is that the human brain is not doing quantum computation. I'm a quantum materials researcher, I've studied the possible mechanisms of quantum computation. The temperature is too high for coherent wave behavior in anything but light, and in order to use light, you would need receptors extraordinarily sensitive to polarization and phase. That requirement simply isn't present in the brain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to explain. The more you explain, the more you risk of rising an eyebrow in your readers, because you will end up stumbling in one of those nitty gritty details which make the entire castle of fiction collapse. And if you don't happen to stumble on them, congratulation, you have just given away a money worth patent in your fictional work.

Just stay high level, with generic statements like "neurons work due to some quantum phenomena, so it's not hard to interface them with a quantum computer once you know the trick". Nobody is going to read your work as a way to get their PhD in Quantum Computers.